# Understanding designing for the iphone images for Iphone5/4/3

Tags: ios, uibutton, photoshop, iphone-5, slice

I would like to understand the thought process/best practice for designing images for an IOS application.

For example I have a button setup as follows:

```
LoginButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,(otherLoginButton.bounds.size.height + 40),300,50)];
```

So the button in code is 300x50px.

My question is what size should the image be within photoshop. Let's take an example that I am designing the whole button as an image not using stretchable buttons etc (although I will be), but as an example I want to create the whole button in PS.

What size should the button be if I am designing for iPhone5 first and then scaling down?

Secondly, once the image is created would all I need to do is scale down in Photoshop by 50% if I used the above technique? Is it as simple as going to scale within Photohshop and choosing 50% or anything else to complete as well.

Once complete, would I then need only these two images for the button one named 'button' the other 'button2@' ?

Comment: the case with `buttons` is not the same as for screen `backgrounds`. You should simply make two example for every button, so for example a button with `100*50px` dimensions and called `button1.png` for iPhone3 (no retina) should have its equivalent for iPhone4/5, so `200*100px`and named `button1@2x.png`

Comment: @Malloc - per the above question would the iphone3 image not be 300x50, then the retina image 600x100?

Comment: Yes, iPhone 3 arts should be doubled for the retina display. So yes, it would be 600x100 for your example.

Comment: @Malloc - Can you confirm the answer to the questions on scaling down and submit as an answer and I can accept, thanks for confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For screen background images. You should take into consideration a 176 px as the difference between iPhone5 and 4 (1136 vs 960), you may consider rework all backgrounds to set your app iPhone5 compatible.

A while ago, I found a great article on how to optimize those arts for iPhone5, have a look [here](http://www.vickiwenderlich.com/2012/11/four-ways-to-deal-with-the-longer-iphone-5-screen/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the share, that answers everything. I like the second option of creating the long images which would only be seen on iphone5 and the iphone4/3 you would not see it.